# How to change rank according to data changes

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I want to have a window function to rank the month according to their values. So in this example, 2018-12 be rank 1, 2019-01 be 2, etc.

And I also want the rank counter to reset after it goes to a new cohort, in this case, cohort 2, the rank should start from 1 again, and the pattern will be similar to cohort 1

```
SELECT *,
   rank() over (partition by cohort, month order by month asc)
FROM (
    SELECT 1 as cohort, id, date_trunc('month',start_date) as month
    FROM _analysis.terms
    WHERE holiday=FALSE and id >= 125 
    UNION SELECT 2, id, date_trunc('month', start_date) FROM _analysis.terms
    WHERE holiday=FALSE and id >= 126
    ORDER BY cohort, id, month
)
ORDER BY cohort, id, month
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help

```
USE AdventureWorks2014
GO
SELECT SalesOrderID,OrderDate
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY  MONTH(OrderDate) ASC) [Rank] 
FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!!! saved my day. why would dense rank in this case not assigning two same order date as two separate rank?

Comment: It is ordered by month not order date. 
MONTH('date') returns month for for assigned date.